# First Person Map View in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am currently developing an **iOS** app using Objective-C and I came across with a requirement from my client that I am unsure and unaware if it can be made.

The app that I am working with is Map based using the geolocalization of the user at all times. To do so, as I am sure you all know, I am using the `MapKit.framework` that Apple gives us pre-built.

My doubt came when my client asked me if it’s possible to use the **First Person Maps View** instead of the traditional `2D Map`. To make my question clear to you, what I was exactly asked if there is any chance to use the same view of the `GPS` navigation in the app (See picture below). Is there any way to do so? If so, could you give me some guides to achive that?

[image]

Any help would be appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours of research I've found a way to do so. The key property is initialized trough:

```
MKMapCamera *mapCamera = [MKMapCamera cameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate:ground fromEyeCoordinate:eye eyeAltitude:50];
```

Take a look at this tutorial if you are need of an explanation step by step:

http://nscookbook.com/2013/10/ios-programming-recipe-30-using-3d-mapping/